# 400 (Bad Request) from Django Ajax sending Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

## **How to show simple message in ajax**

## In below code url going to my view in the view else block but giving 400 bad request,

> > when i am approving url is going to view and printing else message in coomand line but again giving 400 bad request

```
function approveEmployeeTimesheet(emp_id) {
        //$("#approveTimesheet").off("click");
        var yearMonth = $("#timesheetYearMonth").val();
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to Approve ?", function (result) {
            if(result) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'user:Check_pending_request_approve_timesheet' %}",
                    data: {"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{csrf_token}}", "year_month": yearMonth, "emp_id": emp_id},
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "{% url 'user:approve_employee_timesheet' %}",
                            data: {"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{csrf_token}}", "year_month": yearMonth, "emp_id": emp_id},
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function(result) {
                                // hide the edit, approve buttons.
                                $("#approveTimesheet").hide();
                                $("#sendEditLink").hide();
                                $("#sendEditLinkApproveDiv").html("<div class='text-success' style='display:table;'><b><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Approved by "+result.timesheetApprovedBy+"</b></div>");

                                var myToast = Toastify({
                                 text: "Timesheet Approved",
                                 duration: 3000,
                                 gravity: 'bottom'
                                });
                                myToast.showToast();
                                getEmpTimesheets(emp_id)
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        bootbox.alert("Please Approve/Reject the pending requests under tab");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: any Error in python function?

Comment: No error data is not available its going to else part  when im printing in else something it is printing but giveing 400 bad req again.. @HemalPatel

Comment: can you share the function? and also do try and exceptions to see errors if any.